# Add to home screen explicitly?

Tags: android, google-chrome

This [Google developer article on Add to Home Screen](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) opens with the following:

> Add to Home Screen, sometimes referred to as the web app install prompt makes it easy for users to add your Progressive Web App to their app launcher and home screen. Chrome handles most of the heavy lifting for you, and on Android, Chrome will generate a WebAPK creating an even more integrated experience for your users.

It then goes onto explaining how to implement a handler for the **beforeinstallprompt** and so on.

My question is whether the "Add to Home Screen" described here is the same as the "Add to Home Screen" option in Android Chrome browser toolbar which is available on any page.

More specifically:

1. Do I need to go through all the steps in that article if the user already knows to use the browser toolbar route?
2. Is the end result the same regardless of which route the user goes through?

Reason I ask: I followed the code in the article, but as my page didn't raise a **beforeinstallprompt** (not looking for help on this right now) I installed using the toolbar, but still got a console log for the **appinstalled** event, so it seems it is the same thing. But, I'm not getting some of the features promised by a WebAPK (e.g. it still shows up as WebApp in the task manager, or in installed apps).

Also, the article states:

> Attention: Beginning in Chrome 68 (beta in early June 2018), Chrome will not automatically show the Add to Home Screen banner, instead, you can show it by calling prompt() on the beforeinstallprompt event with a user gesture. See Updates to Add to Home Screen Behavior for full details.

I take it this won't affect the "Add to Home Screen" function in the browser toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that most users do not know how to add to the home screen (A2HS).
Many probably know how to bookmark or add a favourite.

Currently, if your PWA passes all of the criteria, Android users for Chrome & Edge will AUTOMATICALLY be prompted by those browsers.
This is still happening in beta chrome 68 with a temporary snack-bar.

The end result is the same, but you want to have the option to offer it to the user, not depend on them knowing about options in their browser.